# unable to right to a variable from another script in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

Trying to access variable gravity in this script

```
extends KinematicBody2D
class_name Actor 

export var speed: = Vector2(300.0, 1000.0)
export var gravity = 3000.0 


var velocity: = Vector2.ZERO
func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    velocity.y += gravity*delta 
    #velocity.y = max(velocity.y, speed.y)
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

from this script

```
extends Actor

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    var direction = Vector2(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left"),0.0
    )


velocity =
```

I get the error Unexpected token: Identifier:velocity

am I using class_name incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access both `velocity` and `gravity` variables from base class, but you need to do it within a function, e.g.:

```
extends Actor

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    velocity += Vector2.ZERO #  just an example
```